# Split string using regular expression in Go

Tags: regex, go, split

I'm trying to find a good way to split a string using a regular expression instead of a string. Thanks

http://nsf.github.io/go/strings.html?f:Split!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you just want to split on certain characters, you can use `strings.FieldsFunc`, otherwise I'd go with `regexp.FindAllString`.

Comment: I tried this, but it overwrites the character I want to split on. I don't want to lose the character, just insert a space. I used a for loop to get to my goal. Thanks. PS - your answer didn't include regex, maybe that's why there's a down vote?

Comment: Nothing is getting "overwritten", it's just a question of what was returned. If you like, you can always use a different regexp function to get the indices and use those.

Answer (score 43):

You can use `regexp.Split` to split a string into a slice of strings with the regex pattern as the delimiter.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("[0-9]+")
    txt := "Have9834a908123great10891819081day!"

    split := re.Split(txt, -1)
    set := []string{}

    for i := range split {
        set = append(set, split[i])
    }

    fmt.Println(set) // ["Have", "a", "great", "day!"]
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 19):

I made a regex-split function based on the behavior of regex split function in java, c#, php.... It returns only an array of strings, without the index information.

```
func RegSplit(text string, delimeter string) []string {
    reg := regexp.MustCompile(delimeter)
    indexes := reg.FindAllStringIndex(text, -1)
    laststart := 0
    result := make([]string, len(indexes) + 1)
    for i, element := range indexes {
            result[i] = text[laststart:element[0]]
            laststart = element[1]
    }
    result[len(indexes)] = text[laststart:len(text)]
    return result
}
```

example:

```
fmt.Println(RegSplit("a1b22c333d", "[0-9]+"))
```

result:

```
[a b c d]
```

Answer (score 16):

The [regexp.Split()](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.Split) function would be the best way to do this.

Comment: Looks like this was [added in Go 1.1](https://golang.org/doc/go1.1) ([May 2013](https://golang.org/doc/devel/release.html#go1.1)).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create your own split function that loops over the results of RegExp.FindAllString, placing the intervening substrings into a new array.

http://nsf.github.com/go/regexp.html?m:Regexp.FindAllString!

Comment: Not sure where you got `RegExp` from, but the correct package name is `regexp`. Go is case-sensitive!

Answer (score 2):

I found this old post while looking for an answer. I'm new to Go but these answers seem overly complex for the current version of Go. The simple function below returns the same result as those above.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func goReSplit(text string, pattern string) []string {
    regex := regexp.MustCompile(pattern)
    result := regex.Split(text, -1)
    return result
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", goReSplit("Have9834a908123great10891819081day!", "[0-9]+"))
}
```