# Split a string on whitespace in Go?

Tags: regex, go

Given an input string such as `"  word1   word2 word3   word4  "`, what would be the best approach to split this as an array of strings in Go? Note that there can be *any* number of spaces or unicode-spacing characters between each word.

In Java I would just use `someString.trim().split("\\s+")`.

(Note: possible duplicate [Split string using regular expression in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466091/split-string-using-regular-expression-in-go) doesn't give any good quality answer. Please provide an actual example, not just a link to the `regexp` or `strings` packages reference.)

Comment: If you ended up on this page. This is what you are looking for: strings.SplitN(s, sep string, n int) []string

Answer (score 398, accepted):

The `strings` package has a [`Fields`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields) method.

```
someString := "one    two   three four "

words := strings.Fields(someString)

fmt.Println(words, len(words)) // [one two three four] 4
```

***DEMO:*** http://play.golang.org/p/et97S90cIH

From the docs:

> Fields splits the string s around each instance of one or more consecutive white space characters, as defined by unicode.IsSpace, returning a slice of substrings of s or an empty slice if s contains only white space.

Comment: Unfortunately, `strings.Fields` doesn't ignore spaces in quoted parts.

Comment: @chmike True, but the moment quotes get involved, you're in the business of *decoding* or *parsing* some specific *encoding* or *format*.

Comment: @chmike you might need `shlex` for that https://godoc.org/github.com/google/shlex

Answer (score 12):

If you're using tip: [regexp.Split](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.Split)

```
func (re *Regexp) Split(s string, n int) []string
```

Split slices s into substrings separated by the expression and returns
a slice of the substrings between those expression matches.

The slice returned by this method consists of all the substrings
of s not contained in the slice returned by FindAllString. When called
on an expression that contains no metacharacters, it is equivalent to strings.SplitN.

Example:

```
s := regexp.MustCompile("a*").Split("abaabaccadaaae", 5)
// s: ["", "b", "b", "c", "cadaaae"]
```

The count determines the number of substrings to return:

```
n > 0: at most n substrings; the last substring will be the unsplit remainder.
n == 0: the result is nil (zero substrings)
n < 0: all substrings
```

Comment: this seems like an overkill

Comment: @Tom But it's still interesting even if it's not the best answer here. I upvoted this answer because I learned something.

Comment: You should note that `Fields()` won't return empty strings. So the number of fields returned will vary. If you're trying to parse something consistent, then it won't work for you. You might need to use regex if a `FieldsFunc()` also won't work.

Answer (score 7):

I came up with the following, but that seems a bit too verbose:

```
import "regexp"
r := regexp.MustCompile("[^\\s]+")
r.FindAllString("  word1   word2 word3   word4  ", -1)
```

which will evaluate to:

```
[]string{"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"}
```

Is there a more compact or more idiomatic expression?

Answer (score 4):

You can use package strings function split
strings.Split(someString, " ")

[strings.Split](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split)

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations to questions and not posting purely code answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Also, please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.

Comment: That's ok, but won't work for tabs, newlines and other whitespaces

Comment: Also does not work for multiple spaces in a row, as stated in the question.