# Golang: how to read only specified columns from a tab delimited file?

Tags: matlab, go

In Golang do we have a way to read only certain columns like textscan in matlab, e.g.:

```
txt = textscan(op,'%s%*s%s%*s');
```

Thanks!

Comment: An example of the file's content would be useful.

Comment: You can read a line with bufio.ReadString and then break that into indexable columns with strings.Fields or strings.Split. Or you can use the regexp package for unlimited power.

Comment: Adding on to @Aedolon , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737745/split-a-string-on-whitespace-in-go#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your file is basically a TSV file (that is, a CSV file with tabs instead of commas), you can make a very simple wrapper around stdlib's [`csv.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Reader):

```
type FieldsReader struct {
    *csv.Reader
    fields []int
}

func (r *FieldsReader) Read() (record []string, err error) {
    rec, err := r.Reader.Read()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    record = make([]string, len(r.fields))
    for i, f := range r.fields {
        record[i] = rec[f]
    }

    return record, nil
}
```

Full code and usage example: http://play.golang.org/p/YcwOmsMX2B.