# Golang regex : Ignore multiple occurrences

Tags: regex, go

I've got a simple need.
Giving this input (string) : 10 20 30 40 65 45 44 67 100 200 65 40 66 88 65

I need to get all numbers between 65 and 66.
Problem is when we have multiple occurrence of each limit.
With a regex like : (65).+(66), I captured 65 45 44 67 100 200 65 40 66. But I would like to get only 40.

How could I achieve this ?

https://regex101.com/r/9HoKxr/1

Comment: For this to work, a tempered greedy token is usually used, but it requires the use of a lookahead. It is not quite easy to handle this case in RE2 regex flavor. Maybe all you want is to get the last instance of `65` before the `66`? `.*65(.*?)66`?

Comment: Besides, are you sure you are not oversimplifying the task? What about a `40 65 45 6544 40 66 200` input?

Comment: Regarding current context, it should be 45 6544 40. Even if 65 is part of 6544.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want to exclude matching '65' inside the number of your pattern upto the 1st occurence of '66'? It's a bit verbose but what about:

```
\b65((?:\s(?:\d|[1-57-9]\d|6[0-47-9]|\d{3,}))+?)\s66\b
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iGrBLo/1)

---

- `\b65\s` - Start with '65' between a word-boundary and a whitespace char;
- `(` - Open capture group;

  - `(?:\s` - Non-capture group with the constant of a whitespace char;
  - `(?:\d|[1-57-9]\d|6[0-46-9]|\d{3,})` - Nested non-capture group to match any integer but '65' or '66';
  - `)+?)` - Close non-capture group and match it at least once but as few times as possible. Then close the capture group;
- `\s66\b` - Match another space followed by '66' and word-boundary.

---

**Note:**

- We will handle leading spaces with the `Trim()` function through the strings package;
- That in my examples I have used '10 20 30 40 65 45 44 40 66 200 65 40 66 88 65' which should return multiple matches. In such case it's established OP is looking for the 'shortest' matching substring;
- By 'shortest' it's meant that we are looking for the least amount of elements when the substring is split with spaces (using ['Fields'](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Fields) function from above mentione strings package). Therefor '123456' is prefered above '1 2 3' despite being the 'longer' substring in terms of characters;

Try:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := `10 20 30 40 65 45 44 40 66 200 65 40 66 88 65`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\b65((?:\s(?:\d|[1-57-9]\d|6[0-47-9]|\d{3,}))+?)\s66\b`)
    matches := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1) // Retrieve all matches

    shortest := ``
    for i, _ := range matches { // Loop over array
        if shortest == `` || len(strings.Fields(matches[i][1])) < len(strings.Fields(shortest)) {
            shortest = strings.Trim(matches[i][1], ` `)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(shortest)
}
```

Try it for yourself [here](https://go.dev/play/p/VRrB8m4fF1f).

Comment: its a new learning for me that go supports `\d` and `[0-9]` both are supported, very nice answer, cheers.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13. I hope I interpreted the question correctly.

Comment: @JvdV Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. Impressive.

Comment: @gab, you are welcome. Please do note that this is about the shortest substring in the end. Not about the least amount of integers between `65` and `66`. Note that `123456` is longer than `1 2 3` whereas the 1st is actually just a single element where the 2nd == 3. Yet the 2nd one will be returned in the above answer. Is this ok?

Comment: @JvdV What I forgot to say is that this list of numbers are not coming in one time. So, we shouldn't care of multiples match as soon as there is not overlap. Besides, you answered clearly to the initial question ! But my real context is that each bound could change, as a parameter to this function and to regex pattern, and they could also be multiples numbers. I need to figure out how to manage this now.

Comment: @JvdV you're right. It should be the first one coming, not the shortest.

Comment: @gab, see the edited answer. Including [`strings`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13737890/9758194) package we can count the 'words' (space-delimited elements) per captured substring and retrieve the substring with the least amount of elements in it.