# Regular expression for repeating pattern

Tags: regex, go

I have the following input text:

`pagelimit=50&filtercolumn=Datacenter&filtervalue=abfg1&filtercolumn=MachineType&filtervalue=fg&filtercolumn=GPG&filtervalue=IPMI`

I want to get back

1. `filtercolumn=Datacenter&filtervalue=abfg1`
2. `filtercolumn=MachineType&filtervalue=fg`
3. `filtercolumn=GPG&filtervalue=IPMI`

There may be an unlimited amount of these.

I have tried a few things. I'm currently trying something like this:

```
(?:((filtercolumn=.*&filtervalue=.*)+)?)
```

But of course it doesn't work. I get:

1. `filtercolumn=Datacenter&filtervalue=abfg1&filtercolumn=MachineType&filtervalue=fg&filtercolumn=GPG&filtervalue=IPMI`
2. `filtercolumn=Datacenter&filtervalue=abfg1&filtercolumn=MachineType&filtervalue=fg&filtercolumn=GPG&filtervalue=IPMI`

Comment: check this post for using regex in Go to split strings. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466091/split-string-using-regular-expression-in-go

Comment: That string looks suspiciously like URL query parameters (the stuff after `http://.../path?`) and if it is then [(net/url).ParseQuery](https://godoc.org/net/url#ParseQuery) might be a useful tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this `\bfiltercolumn=[^&]*&filtervalue=[^&]*`

https://regex101.com/r/sasmXL/2

Comment: Definitely works in that site. Now trying to try it out in go. What is the \b doing?

Comment: It's just a word boundary, it prevents matching something like `autofiltercolumn=...&filtervalue=...`

Comment: Probably doing something dumb. but I have  `a := regexp.MustCompile("\bfiltercolumn=[^&]*&[^&]*")
 var c = a.Split(r.URL.RawQuery, -1) `   returns a single item array of:  `pagelimit=50&filtercolumn=Datacenter&filtervalue=vin1&filtercolumn=MachineType&filtervalue=sd&filtercolumn=APC&filtervalue=IPMI `

Comment: I don't use go lang so I can't help you with regex usage. If the regex works on regex101 under the _golang_ tag, it definitely works in code. I would check to make sure it's a global match and that the `"\b"` doesn't need to be escaped `"\\b"` as well.

Comment: I just needed to use FindAllString instead of split. Thanks for the help.